# Deleting all files matching a regular expression in chef

Tags: chef-infra

I would like my chef recipe to delete all files that match a certain regex. What would be the way to go about this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could use an `execute` resource in your recipe:

```
execute "Deleting files ... " do
    command "find . -regex 'REGEX' -delete"
    cwd "/path/to/folder"
    action :run
end
```

The command expects a target system having the `find` command.

Comment: Does `find` work without path? Should it not be `command "find . -regex 'REGEX' -delete"` ??

Comment: @Shrinath Yes, with GNU find you can omit the folder. It defaults to the current folder in that case. Imo that is a convenient solution that works like other tools. Or would you type `ls .`? Anyhow, I've added the dot to make the command work on a mac.

Answer (score 11):

Depending on your use case, the previous answers may work. However, using bash's native delete functionality is not cross-platform. Additionally, depending on the level of control you need over the resources, you may want to use a more Ruby-like approach:

```rb
Dir["/path/to/folder/{YOUR_REGEX}"].each do |path|
  file ::File.expand_path(path) do
    action :delete
  end
end
```

This will create a unique entry in the resource collection for each file that matches the regex. It is also idempotent (meaning it won't run if the files are already deleted) and cross-platform (it will work on Windows too).

Comment: Note that you can't use regex this way, but glob patterns.

Answer (score 2):

A scenario where you'd want to do this is cleaning up files installed/setup from a previous version of a recipe.

I found this cookbook that provides several useful recipes for these cleanup purposes: https://github.com/nvwls/zap

```ruby
zap_directory '/etc/sysctl.d' do
   pattern '*.conf'
end

zap_crontab 'root' do
  pattern 'test \#*'
end

zap_users '/etc/passwd' do
    # only zap users whose uid is greater than 500
    filter { |u| u.uid > 500 }
end
```