# Deleting some but not all sub directories using Chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have several sub-directories inside a parent directory that I need to remove using my cookbook, but there are many other sub-directories I need to keep. Is there a programmatic way I can achieve the delete of certain sub-directories or do I have to manually specify each one that I wish to remove like so;

```
directory "/var/lib/foo" do
  action :delete
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just specify a desired pattern with a regular expression and delete all (sub)directories matching that pattern.

Something like that:

```
Dir["/main/{sub1,sub2,sub3}"].each do |dir|
  file ::File.expand_path(dir) do
    action :delete
  end
end
```

For more information on how to match the desired files using `Dir` see the [Ruby docs on Dir](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Dir.html).

[This related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431500/deleting-all-files-matching-a-regular-expression-in-chef) might also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

That depends entirely on how you decide what to keep and what to get rid of.  Assuming you have a list of directories to remove....

```
%w(/this/path /this/otherpath /this/one/too).each do |dir|
  file ::File.expand_path(dir) do
    action :delete
  end
end
```

or

```
parent = '/some/long/path'
%w(child other/child and/this/one) do |child|
  file ::File.join(parent, child) do
    action :delete
  end
end
```